# How does reduceByKey and mapValues works simultaneously?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am completely new to spark and in the world of big data. I have a code which actually creates a function which splits a CSV file and returns two fields.

Then there is map function which I know how it works, but I am confused in next part of the code (operation happening on **totalsByAge** variable) , mapValues and reduceByKey are applying. Please help me to understand how reduceByKey and mapValues works here?

```
def parseLine(line):
fields = line.split(',')
age = int(fields[2])
numFriends = int(fields[3])
return (age,numFriends)

line = sparkCont.textFile("D:\\ResearchInMotion\\ml-100k\\fakefriends.csv")
rdd = line.map(parseLine)
totalsByAge = rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
averagesByAge = totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])
results = averagesByAge.collect()
for result in results:
    print(result)
```

I need help in **totalsByAge** variable processing.It would be good if you can also elaborate the operation done on **averagesByAge**  Please let me know if anything is missing.

Answer (score 1):

In the line of `rdd = line.map(parseLine)` you have pair of values in the format of `(age, numFriends)` like `(a_1, n_1), (a_2, n_2), ..., (a_m, n_m)`. In `rdd.mapValues(lambda x: (x, 1))` you will get `(a_1, (n_1, 1)), (a_2, (n_2, 1)), ..., (a_m, (n_m, 1))`.

In `reduceByKey`, first grouped by key, it means all the same `age` grouped in a group and you will have something likes `(a_i, iterator over pairs of (n_j, 1) which all n_j has the same age)`, and after that apply the function of the reduction. And reduction part means sum all `numFriends` with each other for each age, and `1`s with each other, which sum of `1`s means the number items in the list.

Therefore, after `reduceByKey`, we will have `(a_i, (sum of all numFriends in the list, number of items in the list))`. In the otherwords, the first value of the outside pair is `age` and second value is a inside pair which its first value is sum of all `numFriends` and the second value is the number of items. Hence, `totalsByAge.mapValues(lambda x: x[0] / x[1])` gives us average of `numFriends` for each `age`.